# expo-notifications scheduleNotification is not working as expected in devices

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, expo-notifications

My app is of `expo bare workflow`.

Using latest expo & expo notifications.

```
"expo": "^39.0.0",
"expo-notifications": "~0.7.2",
```

### Problem

Im im trying to schedule a repeat notification on everyday morning 9AM & night 9PM everyday. One Everytime use user opens app, im cancelling all old notifications & scheduling new one, (tried with checking scheduled notification, if not exist schedule new). This seems to be working fine in android simulator, when i install app in phone it triggers notification very rarely or some times nothing for a week. I have just followed given documentation for repeat local notifications. Need help...

#### Code

```
// Cancel All notifications
await Notifications.cancelAllScheduledNotificationsAsync();
//9AM notification
        await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
            identifier: 'morning-1',
            content: {
                title: `Good Morning!`,
                subtitle: 'Greetings',
                body: `Have a great day`,
                sound: true,
                color: "#ffffff",
                data: {
                    to: 'new-log'
                }
            },
            trigger: {
                hour: 9,
                minute: 0,
                repeats: true
            }
        });
    

   //9PM notification
    await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
                identifier: 'night-notification',
                content: {
                    title: `Good Night :)`,
                    subtitle: 'Have a great sleep :D',
                    body: `Have a great sleep :D',
                    sound: true,
                    data: {
                        to: 'new-log'
                    },
                    color: "#000000"                },
                trigger: {
                    hour: 21,
                    minute: 0,
                    repeats: true
                }
            });
```

But it doesn't trigger notifications properly, what i observed, it will show notifications like 3 days once or weekly once or sometimes nothing. it is not trigger on given time at all.

**Update**
Apparently its battery optimization of UIs like MIUI, Oxygen OS causing notification not to appear when device is in doze mode. The workaround which i found is to ask user to turn off battery optimization for the app. But i feel notifications should override dozemode regardless of battery optimization...

Comment: Did you find any other solution other than turning off the battery optimization?

Comment: nothing. i have stoped workin on it